# "Float" against centered element from both sides without flexbox?

Tags: css, css-float, centering

For the header of a website, I want to center an element and have to rows of links float against it from both sides. The rows are not the same length, so I can't just center the whole menu.

It's easier to see than to explain, so here's an image and a fiddle of the effect I want to achieve.
[image: effect]
http://jsbin.com/katuroxi/11/edit

The fiddle however uses the new `flexbox`, which I would like to (if possible) avoid.
Is there a way to do this without them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it [like this](http://jsbin.com/katuroxi/19/edit):

```
.parent {
  display: table;
  table-layout:fixed;
  padding: 0;
  font-size:0px;
  width:100%;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.left, .right, .fix {
  display:table-cell;
}

.left {
  text-align: right;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-size:16px;
}

.fix {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 120px;
  font-size:16px;
}
```

What this does is:

- add `display:table` to the `.parent` and make it render with table-like logic and make it `100%`.
- add `display:table-cell` to `.left, .right, .fix` so it will render like a table cell. Because of this, each cell will take `33%` of the table width.
- add `font-size:0px` to the `.parent` to remove the white space between `display:inline-block` elements.
- set the `font-size` back to the desired value in the elements where we have the text.

Comment: Not a *very* beautiful solution, but certainly a compatible one. Thank you for the quick response!

Comment: You are welcome! Btw, don't worry about using table-like stuff. Most of the ugliness that surrounds using tables for layout don't apply to using `display:table` in this situation :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use all elements as `display:inline;` (or `display:inline-block` if you want some padding) and `text-align:center;` on the `.parent`

```
.parent {
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline;
}

.left, .right, .fix {
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
}

li, .fix {
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/katuroxi/12/edit

Comment: Like I said, the two sides are not necessarily of the same width. I should've selected imbalanced ones for the fiddle. Here's what your solution looks like with four on the right and three on the left: http://jsbin.com/katuroxi/17/edit

Comment: As you can see here http://jsbin.com/katuroxi/15/edit the `center` element doesn't stay center if you add more links on either side.